# Alt-Key stopped working in gnome-terminal after upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: upgrade, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

For example I cannot switch between the tabs in gnome-terminal with Alt+1, Alt+2 anymore. Shortcuts in general and Menu shortcuts specifically, are enabled via the global gnome-terminal settings.

When I hit Alt + 1 it looks like this.

[image]

And it's the same behaviour without tmux:
[image]

I already opened an issue in the gnome-terminal repo, but it was rejected. It really decreases the usability of the gnome-terminal for me.

I'd be happy to find any solution to that, even if it requires a bit of effort.

Comment: I also upgraded my notebook from 18.10 to 19.04 several weeks ago, but Alt+1, Alt+2, etc. do work in my gnome Terminal. Did you check **Shortcuts** in **Preferences** of Terminal?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Yes, they are set.

Comment: Output of `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`:

`169/5000 There is only one alternative in link group x-terminal emulator (which provides / usr / bin / x-terminal-emulator): /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper Nothing to configure.`

Comment: Same here, just upgraded to 19.04. Shortcuts also set in preferences.

Comment: I have the same problem and replaced all shortcuts to Ctrl+[n]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Alt-# shortcuts start working again when I disable "Enable mnemonics" for some reason. The menu shortcuts don't work with the menu bar hidden anyway, so I don't miss that setting.

Comment: Where can you disable that?

Comment: Oops, it's in Preferences under General.

Comment: Seems contradictory to deactivate something to make it work, but who know's what genius puzzled that out. Switching tabs with Alt+1, Alt+2, etc. works only when I don't enable shortcuts (re-translated from German UI).

Comment: it has fixed my problem as well! Thanks

Comment: For posterity - this also happens when upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, and this solution fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: if you cannot find the setting (like me in MATE 20.04), you can do this in `dconf-editor`, too, just disable all `mnemonics`-like fields (unless you are completely addict for some reason)